# How to copy elements from an ArrayList to another one NOT by reference?

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor, pass-by-value

I'm trying to copy each element from one ArrayList (av) to another one (copia). The thing is that they're copied by reference, so whenever I make any changes in the original one, the copy is modified as well. Of course, this behavior is not wanted. How should I write this method?

```
public void copiarArrayList(ArrayList<Articulo_Venta> copia, ArrayList<Articulo_Venta> av){
    copia.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < av.size(); i++) {
        copia.add(av.get(i));
    }
}
```

Articulo_Venta has these fields:

```
int codigo;
String nombre;
float cantidad;
```

PS: I also tried the next:

```
copia = new ArrayList<Articulo_Venta>(av);
```

but it still has its elements pointing to the original ArrayList.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you want is the deep copy. If your object contains only primitive you could use clone(), otherwise best way is to do manually:-

Make a constructor in your `Articulo_Venta` class which takes another `Articulo_Venta` object and initializes member variables.

Then change the code as:-

```
public void copiarArrayList(ArrayList<Articulo_Venta> copia, ArrayList<Articulo_Venta> av){
        copia.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < av.size(); i++) {
            copia.add(new Articulo_Venta(av.get(i)));
        }
```

Also read here - [how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java)

Comment: That was it! It's quite annoying having to do this, but the solution is to copy each field of the object individually into a new object, and to add it to the new ArrayList. Thanks and happy New Year!

Comment: you save my life :)

Answer (score 1):

Cloning the objects before adding them. For example, instead of `newList.addAll(oldList);`

```
for(Articulo_Venta av : oldList) {
    newList.add(av.clone());
}
```

clone should be correctly overriden in Articulo_Venta.

This is how you do it.

```
public class Articulo_Venta {

String a;  //assuming you have these fields, then
Date d;
...

public Articulo_Venta clone(){
    Articulo_Venta  av = new Articulo_Venta();
    av.a = this.a.clone();
    av.d = this.d.clone();
    ...
    return av;
}
}
```

Comment: But what if av contains more references to other objects, won't clone copy them all?

Comment: Try not to override clone in Java:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270369/what-have-you-used-object-clone-for

Comment: @MangatRaiModi yeah I know you cannot clone primitives. Thats why I didn't include any primitive in my example :P

Answer (score 1):

Create a new constructor in your class Articulo_Venta.

```
public Articulo_Venta(int codigo, String number, float candidad)
{
  this.codigo = codigo;
  this.number = number;
  this.candidad = candidad;
}

public void copiarArrayList(List<Articulo_Venta> copia, List<Articulo_Venta> av)
{
   av.stream().forEach(t -> {
     Articulo_Venta newObj = new Articulo_Venta(t.getCodigo(), t.getNumber(), t.getCandidad());
     copia.add(newObj);
   });
}
```

Comment: This would work too, but it's a little simpler to make a constructor with Articulo_Venta as argument.